# Why is the expected length of a chain in hashing equal to $n/m$ (the load factor) due to independence of collisions?

Tags: probability, computer-science

Say we have inserted $n$ keys and that we have $m$ slots and that the [Simple Uniform Hashing Assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUHA_(computer_science)) holds (each item to be hashed has an equal probability of being placed into a slot, regardless of the other elements already placed). This means that all keys insertions are independent of each other and don't affect each other how one key goes to any slot. Does this independence assumption justify this reasoning: Let $n_j = T[j]$ be the length of a chain in position j. Then:

$$ \mathbb{E}[T[j]] = \sum^n_{i=1}\frac{1}{m}$$

and we can do this summation $n$ times due to independence. This argument seems completely wrong to me because independence as far as I remember guarantees $Pr[A,B] = Pr[A]Pr[B]$  (or $Pr[A \mid B] = Pr[A]$) but not summation. However, that is the explanation given here:

https://youtu.be/0M_kIqhwbFo?t=38m20s

at one of MIT's OCW lectures. Is the explanation the professor gave justified? Is the summation justified because of the independence, or why can we add things the way he suggested?

Answer (score 2):

Unless I am missing something in the definition of the question, this indeed has nothing to do with independence. This is only [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity), which holds even for arbitrarily dependent random variables:
$$\mathbb{E}[X+Y] = \mathbb{E}[X] +  \mathbb{E}[Y]$$ (provided these expectations all exist).

Here, we fix $j\in[m]$ and consider the random variables $X_1,\dots, X_n$, with $X_i$ corresponding to the indicator of the event *"the $i$-th item goes to slot $j$."* (This is a random variable taking value $0$ or $1$, and $\mathbb{E}\left[X_i\right]=1\cdot \mathbb{P}\{X_i=1\}+ 0 \cdot \mathbb{P}\{X_i=0\} = \mathbb{P}\{X_i=1\}$.)

Then $$\mathbb{E}[T_j] = \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right]=\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}\left[X_i\right] = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}\{X_i=1\} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{m} = \frac{n}{m}.$$

Comment: I have a problem with the term "$\mathbb P\{X_i=1\}$". It would read as "The probability that the $i$-th item goes to slot $j$". But the problem is, there's no probability distribution associated with a particular item since hash functions are deterministic and hash every key to their corresponding fixed slots. Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: @Jamal you may want to read [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing): a hash function is modeled as a family of (deterministic) functions, and the probability is over the choice of the function. It is a little counterintuitive, given the terminology. The Simple Uniform Hashing (SUHA)is then an abstracted assumption for the analysis.

Comment: To my knowledge SUHA is an assumption that states that given a random variable $K$ whose possible values are the universe of keys, the random variable $h(K)$ follows a uniform distribution. Also if $K_1$ and $K_2$ are 2 random variables whose ranges are the universe of keys, then $h(K_1)$ and $h(K_2)$ are independent. I don't see here why universal hashing would be needed. The following answer about SUHA is where I had re-enforced this understanding;
https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/87922/simple-uniform-hashing-unclear-definition-of-probability

Comment: That is the thing. It is an abstraction (a model): you treat the function as a random variable. It may not be consistent with what happens in practice (e.g., h only pseudorandom, or even deterministic) but it's a useful mathematical abstraction (again, an assumption) to prove things; and there are other (complementary/related/analogous) models (s.t. universal families) to understand why we can consider h to be random.

Comment: I will definitely look more into this. To me, changing the hash function in the analysis seems very strange. Especially if SUHA considers hash functions as random variables because it seems to break the whole idea of hashing fixed inputs to fixed values. Nonetheless my knowledge in this area is still budding and I shall keep searching.

Comment: Anyways, it's a bit early for me to improvise an impromptu lecture on how to model hash functions and why, but any reasonable cryptography/computer science textbook should have a discussion of what these assumptions mean, and how they are abstractions/models. :)

Comment: I'm currently reading CLRS and there doesn't seem to be much discourse(with mathematical rigour) on it. I'll look into other sources as well and come back to this answer ^_^. Thank you for this discussion .

Comment: Yes... CLRS has some blind spots. @Jamal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118710/discussion-between-jaml-and-clement-c).